# How to create compile-time constant string with prepended length byte?

Tags: c++, string, constants

I have some old code that uses `#define` to, um, define some string literals, e.g.

```cpp
#define FredString "\004FRED"
```

That I would like to update to avoid using `#define`. Closest I get is something like the following:

```cpp
static constexpr char* FSraw= "FRED";
static constexpr char FSlen= (char)(sizeof(FSraw) - 1);
static constexpr char* FredString= FSlen FSraw;
```

but the compiler seems unhappy on the third line.

What would be the best way to construct such a string at compile time? Obviously I could still explicitly encode the length, but also obviously, that's more error prone.

Looking for solutions for C++17 or earlier.

Comment: waht is the third line supposed to mean? `static constexpr char* FredString = some_number FSraw;` ? String literals are of type `char [N]` btw, ie their lenght is part of their type, no need to store it seperately

Comment: `sizeof(FSraw)` won't work since `FSraw` is a `char*`, you need a `char[]` instead to make that `sizeof()` work properly. `sizeof("FRED")` would work, since a string literal is a `const char[N]`.  But `= FSlen FSraw;` will never work no matter what you do, you can't concat values like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<char, N+1> AddLenPrefix(const char (&str)[N])
{
    std::array<char, N+1> ret{};
    ret[0] = N-1; // Exclude the '\0'.
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ret[i+1] = str[i];
    return ret;
}

static constexpr auto FredString = AddLenPrefix("FRED");
```

Comment: Much nicer than the approach I was trying, using a manual struct with a `constexpr` constructor. This code won't work prior to C++17 though, since `std::array::operator[]` wasn't `constexpr` yet, so `ret[...] = ...;` won't compile, but it will in C++17. Just know that in order to use the `FredString` constant in contexts that expect `const char*` strings, you will have to use `FredString.data()` instead of `FredString` directly since `std::array` doesn't have an implicit conversion operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have something like:

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

template <std::string_view const& S, typename>
struct prepend_length_impl;

template <std::string_view const& S, std::size_t ... Is>
struct prepend_length_impl<S, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    static constexpr const char value[]{ (sizeof...(Is) + '0'), S[Is]..., 0 };
};

template <std::string_view const& S>
struct prepend_length {
    static constexpr std::string_view value =
        prepend_length_impl<S, std::make_index_sequence<S.size()>>::value;
};
```

and then use it like:

```cpp
static constexpr std::string_view raw = "fred";
static constexpr std::string_view fred = prepend_length<raw>::value; // "4fred"
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFYAnKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiEm8ADqgWE6rR6hibmVn4BanT2ji5G7p7eisqYqkEMBMzEBCHGppYpKtG0mdkEsc5uHl68Clk5eWGF9eWV8Ym1AJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzA7IhlgA1OKjOvXEDsAA%2BgBueJgA7nPY4gAMAIJjE1OYs/Pqi5jMRrsHx5LjtJMGM3M6BmqshACe90cHgRMEYfMJgRcFgR0CAQItlutNltpmhaPUpAA2aYMUjTAi/HxaW6YAGHRYGVTTdiiAgIX4rPCg1hzWSAo7ApnMCEfeowuEEJaiRHbFF0dGSLE46a82EBABemBWBGmADo1dMAJIKUnkynU4C0%2BmMsEfKUykAOLAADxWSgAjgYtIMPlq1Sr7qNsLMAOysw7TAPSrJqZCitHAq0%2BYhh%2BoohDZaZrNiO8RmWRmAAi4l90wg8swqCobogWq6sxk0zAQ32VZ62NT0i1qYzbtx%2Bx9WdGfuzne77JBYK55x50NlAoRGxFqPFkp1Aopyv1hp9fsDQa5eFD04jUaDfPhQsnyKThmHoyzRzXa6XdIZTNNuPNRmYAGtFZbMDb7Y6XiT5gwVXzCAug9bBYRPFMuweHsWWg/tOW5eZzQPVYjxjAhMXrT0HgcH5HHQz9d2Q8dDyRKktANW81guDNyJpOlTV2cDkz/PtDgcZVnwcYCVweNdWhDAjI2jYjBVQsjiGYZE5loqRJCoYhMHQOTYMvQMBM3ISiNHfkxOFZEFKUmi6Mo%2Bk1g%2BSSdmwqC1IDc00C%2BSEPmmSynPmPdYRsZkbP9dSdIc5UPmcwz0DcnQPJALzVN8gNFIIfpaGmfZop7IYelYEAhjMIZSFMasctQTKdDkORpT6AZhyeTgcoITL9jSnoX3MUYVQADm9b1JG9MxvQsKrJFa1qMSETLuByvL6tIQqhhyhQQH2Uhavyno4FgGBEBQVBQTwdgyAoCA0G23aQGATh9kkUgqB24FiDmiBXDqnLXAcbJfke0hDqMLQCAAeVoVg3vy0gsGfUR2He/BFPSNZMDmoHPzSL5hkmjjlHen5XEk4hfj0LBMuqxaliMfG0suuhGBYcGeH4QRhFEFASpkIQ8FcObIB6VAfBKOGAFoAHU2FYaZ%2Bc/AVmGFn7RmF3kZIkGQ5E4b1hcJdARBDHmPGIEgFGmWbUnSDQIBsJpTE4axtHaapPDNyJAjoE3BFtkpLYSGozaUYoMgaXJ9HyQQPbSEoyhyF3Ond72HfDtoHCqV3rZ6BRysGLh0sy7Lcve6arSGnmMW4aZgGQUMzpVSRc1wQgSHLUYzemPQjo8avODLYr5ZkGrHq6HoEBuLBPGA0gmu4fYVQsfZh4sDqOvHyQzDNjKhjG0hie4SQVVGbqM6B6bZvmxbO9IVaNr6AgfC%2BchKEOnwdrd6x8CIa2yfoJg2A4amtkknwSdTrLxszzKxicGmFsQgCBpjZwxLnfOhdi4j0kB3Za3de41AHgvJexMeoqgxN4CwuC8H4KsBNAqmVd4LSWvVLug8QDcAxCqTgkgureEkPsb0GJ2qcGpgvUYf9t4kP3ogkaQx4Fb0mjvfhFCegw1ukEahQA%3D%3D%3D)